why can't I find a 2.5 inch shower drain?
I have a fiberglass shower pan that I need a drain for.  The opening for the drain is 2.5 inches. All I am finding is 3 inch.

Shopping questions are defined as off limit.  But, where have you looked?  Only big-box stores?  If that's the case, go to an actual plumbing supply company and I'm sure they'd have what you need.
